# Fann в php, как заставить выходные нейроны запоминать выходы, а не вероятности?

Tags: php, нейронные-сети, fann

Обучаю лёгную нейросеть, которой на вход даю разбитую попиксельно картинку (цвета пикселей) и на выход хочу получить текст на картинке (при обучении его передаю)

- входные нейроны: высота*ширина картинки
- выходные нейроны: 6 (константная длина текста)

Обучаю при помощи `fann_train($ann, inputs_array, outputs_array)` для каждой картинки (так и не смог понять как работать `fann_train_on_data`, а точнее как генерировать ресурс данных обучения)

### Вопрос вот в чём

Fann на выходных нейронах настраивает веса (вероятности), как-же получить готовый текст?

### Возможное глупое решение (прокомментируйте его тоже пожалуйста)

Добавить ко входным нейронам еще 1 (индекс символа, который хочу получить), а кол-во выходных нейронов сделать равным используемому алфовиту и уже по нему получать текст

### Минусы моего решения

- Добавляются новые нейроны, а это означает больший объём занимаемой памяти
- Как минимум в 6 раз уменьшается время обучения и время работы программы в целом

Ps. Не думаю, что листинги кода тут обязательны, однако если они нужны - я добавлю в вопрос (код на другом хранителе)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обучение с учителем. Всегда на выходе вы получите не текст, а вероятность, которую как хотите так и интерпретируете, например от 0 до 1. 
Тогда можно попробовать на вход подать ширину*высоту одной цифры для начала, а выход будет - кол-во символов в картинке=кол-во выходов, в нашем случае пусть будет один.
И попробуем обучать так, на вход нам могут идти цифры от 0 до 9, тогда делим нашу вероятность (от **0** до **1**) на равные промежутки от 0.00 до 0.10 это будет "0", то  если вероятность будет 0.03-0.07 то хорошо определяем это как "0", и так дальше с каждым числом обучаем. ( Дальше от 0.10 до 0.20 это "1", если в 0.13-0.17 укладывается то ок, поверим что "1", а по краям это будет погрешность которую мы не рассматриваем).

> Грубо говоря даём на вход "0" и приучаем сеть выдавать 0.05, берем "2" и
>   приучаем выдавать 0.15 и т.д.
>   Также нужно учесть неточность +-0.02

Попробуй сначала по одному символу учить а потом и весь алфавит, но думаю будет очень медленно определять. А так есть разные типы нейронных сетей для каждой задачи нужна своя грамотно настроенная.

Comment: Можете продемонстрировать на конкретном примере?
Я у себя разбиваю картинку (к примеру: http://prntscr.com/bmkk22, предварительно убрав шумы и приведя к чёрно-белому варианту букв) на пиксели и передаю цвет в нейросеть и передаю то, что сеть должна выводить от этого ввода (в данном случае: Ad4Yfm).